# How to pass xml file path to C++ wrapper from android in SWIG.?

Tags: java, android, c++, swig

I am implemented **swig android module of face detector** in Mac machine.I had successfully generated C++ wrapper cpp source file and JNI java file using Swig module.Generated So file using example_warp.cpp and example.cpp.

**Steps**

1.Get the **absolute path** for face detector xml path in java file and passes to **C++ code.**
2.Converted into Java string into C++ string in Example_wrap.cpp file

```
const char* jnamestr = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(jFileName, NULL);
                string stdFileName(jnamestr);
```

3.The string "**stdFileName**" will be passed into **example.cpp** file

```
example.cpp

int sample(cv::Mat image,cv::Mat &out,cv::Mat &face,std::string stdFileName)
 {

 int z=5;
int z1=10;
int z2=15;

 CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
LOGD("cascade name : %s ",stdFileName.c_str());

   if( face_cascade.load(stdFileName.c_str()) ){ return z; };



  std::vector<Rect> faces;
  Mat frame_gray;

  cvtColor( image, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  cvtColor( image, out, CV_BGR2GRAY );


  //-- Detect faces
  face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|2, Size(30, 30) );



  if(faces.size()>0) {
                 vector_Rect_to_Mat(faces, face);


 // face=frame_gray(faces[0]);
  return z1;
  }

  return z2;
 }
```

4.I got **absolute path** in example.cpp from android.But the xml did not load.

```
  The  absolute path stdFileName.c_str()="/data/data/org.opencv.samples.facedetect/app_cascade/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml"



 if( face_cascade.load(stdFileName.c_str()) ){  return z };
```

5.I got always return **z value as 5** from example.cpp.

How to load above **absolute path** get from android in example.cpp .?